# Different color for each column in angular-chartjs bar chart

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bar-chart, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using angular-chartJS in a project I'm working on and I need a different color for each bar in a Bar Chart.

**Canvas:**

```
<canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="medal_data" labels="medal_ticks"></canvas>
```

**Controller:**

```
$scope.medal_ticks = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Not passed'];
$scope.series = ['Medaljer'];
$scope.medals_colours= ['#087D76', '#B3BC3A', '#38B665', '#8B4A9D'];

$scope.medal_data = ['1', '5', '2', '0'];
```

I've tried to add the attribute `colours="medals_colours"` to my canvas, the only problem is that it uses only the first colour in the array, and what I want is that each colour represents each column. So `#087D76` is used to represent `Gold`, `#B3BC3A` for `Silver`, and so on

Comment: I believe you want this http://plnkr.co/edit/J1cDvM90YGOAmg5CLn3T?p=preview I will add explanation afterwards

Comment: @pankajparkar That is exactly what I need. Thanks! I'll try to figure out what I am missing in the meantime then

Comment: I'll add an answer in an hour.don't spend time on it.surely you will get stuck..I'll update an answer with explaination

Comment: please check the answer which I've added & let me know if you have any queries

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you want to give different color for each bar in graph, you are passing those value in array. But the thing is `chart.js` doesn't support such type of feature.

### Reason

The color which we are able to see in bar area is nothing but `fillColor` option, If you look at the source code of **chart.js** [**Line**](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L2141)

**Code**

```
helpers.each(dataset.data, function(dataPoint, index) {
    //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
    datasetObject.bars.push(new this.BarClass({
        value: dataPoint,
        label: data.labels[index],
        datasetLabel: dataset.label,
        strokeColor: dataset.strokeColor,
        fillColor: dataset.fillColor, //<--This line responsible for filling color
        highlightFill: dataset.highlightFill || dataset.fillColor,
        highlightStroke: dataset.highlightStroke || dataset.strokeColor
    }));
}, this);
```

Above code clearly says that `fillColor` required string. In anyway the you can pass only one color in that string. And only one color will get applied to bar series. If we want to make you requirement workable then we need to make changes in `chart.js`.

### Changes to be made in chart.js

We need to make change in [**this line**](https://github.com/nnnick/Chart.js/blob/master/Chart.js#L2141) from `fillColor: dataset.fillColor,` to `fillColor: dataset.fillColor[index],` so that we can pass color array which needs to be applied on each bar of chart. `index` variable of `.each` will ensure the color would be applied on Bar in order way which we had given in array. Our color would be changed to `$scope.medals_colours = [{fillColor:['#087D76', '#B3BC3A', '#38B665', '#8B4A9D']}];`.

**Changed code**

```
helpers.each(dataset.data, function(dataPoint, index) {
    //Add a new point for each piece of data, passing any required data to draw.
    datasetObject.bars.push(new this.BarClass({
        value: dataPoint,
        label: data.labels[index],
        datasetLabel: dataset.label,
        strokeColor: dataset.strokeColor,
        fillColor: dataset.fillColor[index] || dataset.fillColor, //<--getting color using index
        highlightFill: dataset.highlightFill || dataset.fillColor,
        highlightStroke: dataset.highlightStroke || dataset.strokeColor
    }));
}, this);
```

**Markup**

```
  <div class="graph-display" ng-controller="jsonServerBox">
    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="medal_data" labels="medal_ticks" 
    colours="medals_colours"></canvas>
  </div>
```

**Controller**

```
  app.controller('jsonServerBox', function($scope) {

    $scope.medal_ticks = ['Gold', 'Silver', 'Bronze', 'Not passed'];
    $scope.series = ['Medaljer'];
    $scope.medals_colours = [{fillColor:['#087D76', '#B3BC3A', '#38B665', '#8B4A9D']}];

    $scope.medal_data = [['1', '5', '2', '0']];
  });
```

I know it does look hacky but we have to make it.

Kudos goes to @tpie [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000575/2435473)

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/J1cDvM90YGOAmg5CLn3T?p=preview)

Comment: Annd you were rigtht, couldn't figure it out by myself, but thanks to your great explanation I have managed to make it work with the colors. Thanks a lot man!!!

Comment: @Backer For basic implementation you could refer this http://stackoverflow.com/a/28647813/2435473 your welcome dude.. Glad to help you.. Thanks