# How can I set different colours for each bar in angular-chart.js v1.0.0?

Tags: angularjs, colors, bar-chart, chart.js, angular-chart

How can I do that in angular-chart.js v1.0.0 and off course ChartJS v2.1.6

[How can I set different colours for each bar in angular-chart.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29999963/how-can-i-set-different-colours-for-each-bar-in-angular-chart-js)

Comment: linked answer has everything.. what else you want?

Comment: I want this work in versions above, because the previous post is about angular-chart.js v0.x.x and ChartJS v1.0.x

Answer (score 2):

- Use one dataset for each bar
- Set all data to 0 for the dataset except the data you want to show
- Custom color for each dataset
- BorderWidth = 0 to hide empy data and stacked = true on X axe
- Custom tooltip callback to hide empty dataset

`example`
https://jsfiddle.net/3qas1ar8/3/

Comment: perfect solution frlinw!! thank you so much! I can't vote :( in your solution, I have no reputation...

Comment: @jesus.saad: even if you can't upvote the answer, you should be able to mark it as acceptet.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public barChartColors: Array<any> = [

{
  **backgroundColor: ["#36a2eb", "rgba(47, 132, 71, 0.8)", "rgba(30, 50, 71, 0.8)", "green", "blue", "purple", "orange"
  ],**

  borderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',

  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(105,159,177,1)',

  pointBorderColor: '#fafafa',

  pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fafafa',

  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgba(105,159,177)'
},
```

];

This will provide different color for each bar in a bar-chart.