# Fill Chart js with $http.get() data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, angularjs, charts

Trying to get some data off of a webservice and display it in a chart. I figured chart js would be a good means to do so. (actually using tc-angular-chartjs). The `$http.get( )` call I am using to test is:

```
$http.get('http://myjson.com/1chr1').success(function(data2) {
  data2.forEach(function(r) {
    $scope.labels.push(r.name);
    $scope.scores.push(r.score);
  });
});
```

and here is the whole js file for just the doughnut chart:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module( 'app.doughnut', [] )
  .controller( 'DoughnutCtrl', function ( $scope ) {
    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.scores = [];

    $scope.data = [
      {
        value: 700,
        color:'#F7464A',
        highlight: '#FF5A5E',
        label: 'Red'
      },
      {
        value: 50,
        color: '#46BFBD',
        highlight: '#5AD3D1',
        label: 'Green'
      },
      {
        value: 100,
        color: '#FDB45C',
        highlight: '#FFC870',
        label: 'Yellow'
      }
    ];

    $scope.options =  {

      // Sets the chart to be responsive
      responsive: true,

      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke : true,

      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor : '#fff',

      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth : 2,

      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout : 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts

      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps : 100,

      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing : 'easeOutBounce',

      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate : true,

      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale : false,

      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate : '<ul class="tc-chart-js-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'

    };

  });
```

The issue I am running into is that most of these examples use the same format to supply the chart with data (static data with the same labels like value/label/color/highlight).

For my needs the colors or highlight dont really matter but I need the data pulled from a wesbervice where the value I need for the chart is called `name` and the label for the chart is called `score`.

So I was thinking I could do the `$http.get( )` call and put the labels and scores into 2 different arrays and then the data portion in the js would look something like:

```
$scope.data = {
    labels : ["option 1","option 2","option 3"],
    values : [ 10, 20, 30 ],
    datasets: [ value : values, color : #F7484A, highlight : #FF5A5E, label : labels]
};
```

I saw something like this done for a Chart.js bar graph, but not for a doughnut graph, and I cannot seem to get it to work. Maybe it isnt possible?

Are there any other alternatives? I mean I cannot be the only person who needs to display dynamic data into a nice responsive chart, but all of the examples use static data.

**EDIT ANSWER** I took dubhov's advice. Also found out my webservice link was messed up so I wasnt getting any data :p. Here is the new js for future reference:

```
'use strict';
angular
  .module('app.doughnut', [])
  .controller('DoughnutCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

    $http.get('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1chr1').success(function(data2) {
      $scope.data = [];
      data2.forEach(function(r) {
        $scope.data.push({
          'value': r.score,
          'color': '#F7464A',
          'highlight': '#FF5A5E',
          'label': r.name
        });
      });
    });


    $scope.options = {

      // Sets the chart to be responsive
      responsive: true,

      //Boolean - Whether we should show a stroke on each segment
      segmentShowStroke: true,

      //String - The colour of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeColor: '#fff',

      //Number - The width of each segment stroke
      segmentStrokeWidth: 2,

      //Number - The percentage of the chart that we cut out of the middle
      percentageInnerCutout: 50, // This is 0 for Pie charts

      //Number - Amount of animation steps
      animationSteps: 100,

      //String - Animation easing effect
      animationEasing: 'easeOutBounce',

      //Boolean - Whether we animate the rotation of the Doughnut
      animateRotate: true,

      //Boolean - Whether we animate scaling the Doughnut from the centre
      animateScale: false,

      //String - A legend template
      legendTemplate: '<ul class="tc-chart-js-legend"><% for (var i=0; i<segments.length; i++){%><li><span style="background-color:<%=segments[i].fillColor%>"></span><%if(segments[i].label){%><%=segments[i].label%><%}%></li><%}%></ul>'

    };

  });
```

Comment: Chart.js expects the data to be formatted like it is with the static examples. Can't you just add an object to the data array with the data you need? Like this: `$scope.data.push({'value':r.score, 'label':r.name, 'color':'#RANDOMCOLOR', 'highlight':'#SLIGHTLYSHADEDRANDOMCOLOR'})`

Comment: Here's something to get you started with the random color bits as well: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25709983/769971 I imagine the API doesn't like it when you leave the color attributes out, but haven't tried it myself. That, or if you know your dataset that can be returned is limited, you can just pick from a static list of colors.

Comment: Hey I like this answer. I didn't really think of it that way. But also I wasn't having any luck because my webservice link was messed up :p Thanks tho. If you wanna make those comments into a question I would like to vote it!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry it took so long; at home sick and forgot to check back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chart.js expects the data to be formatted like it is with the static examples. Can't you just add an object to the data array with the data you need? Like this:

```
$scope.data.push({'value':r.score,
                  'label':r.name,
                  'color':'#RANDOMCOLOR',
                  'highlight':'#SLIGHTLYSHADEDRANDOMCOLOR'});
```

As far as the colors, which may or may not be required by the API (I think they will be), you can either go random, or if you know that your dataset is limited, you can select from a static list of colors. Here's some ideas on randoms: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709983/769971