# how to highlight bar in ChartJS with onkeyup Input

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I am trying to make a 'searchable' bar graph in ChartJS, where the user can dynamically search in an input field (onkeyup) for names of x-axis labels. When that label or labels are 'found', that bar (or those bars) are highlighted a different color.

I am not sure how to link the 'input' text and the function that highlights the bar.

Fiddle in progress
https://jsfiddle.net/hironymous_vis/mk0sLfgt/9/

Currently, the search does not work because the input does not link to the function that highlights the bar.

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search...">
```

and

```
function highlightBar(s) {
// this clears off any tooltip highlights
chart1.update();
chart1.activeElements = [];

// reset any coloring because of selection
chart1.datasets.forEach(function(dataset) {
    dataset.bars.forEach(function (bar) {
        if (bar.selected) {
            bar.fillColor = bar.selected.fillColor;
            bar.strokeColor = bar.selected.strokeColor;
            delete bar.selected;
        }
    })
});

var index = chart1.scale.xLabels.indexOf(this.value);
chart1.datasets.forEach(function (dataset) {
    var selectedBar = dataset.bars[index];

    // store the current values
    selectedBar.selected = {
        fillColor: selectedBar.fillColor,
        strokeColor: selectedBar.strokeColor
    }

    // now set the color
    selectedBar.fillColor = "red";
    selectedBar.strokeColor = "red";
});

chart1.update();
}

document.getElementById("myInput").onchange = highlightBar.bind(document.getElementById("myInput"));
document.getElementById("myInput").onchange();
```

Specifically, lines 21 and the function starting on Line 66 in my fiddle. The function is taken from this question: [How to highlight single bar in bar chart using Chartjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154202/how-to-highlight-single-bar-in-bar-chart-using-chartjs)). The difference between this question and that question is that that question had a select dropdown input. I am, instead, trying to have an onkeyup dynamic input.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `dataset.backgroundColor` may be defined as a `string` or as an `array` of strings. Unfortunately this is not clearly reflected in the [Chart.js documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#dataset-properties).

In order to have a specific bar highlighted, you need to define `dataset.backgroundColor` as an array of same colors, the color at the desired index however must be different.

This can be done with the following simple function.

```
function highlightMatchingBar() {
  var searchValue = document.getElementById('search').value.toUpperCase();
  chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = labels.map(v => v.toUpperCase() == searchValue ? 'red' : 'green');
  chart.update();
}
```

Please take a look at below runnable code snippet, enter any valid animal name (case is irrelevant) and see how it works.

```js
const labels = ['Cow', 'Horse', 'Dog', 'Cat', 'Bird', 'Fish', 'Sheep', 'Goat', 'Mouse', 'Rabbit', 'Bee', 'Rat', 'Pig', 'Fly'];
const chart = new Chart(document.getElementById('myChart'), {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: "My Dataset",
      data: labels.map(l => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000) + 1),
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }]
  },
  options: {
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    scales: {
      yAxes: [{
        ticks: {
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }]
    }
  }
});

function highlightMatchingBar() {
  var searchValue = document.getElementById('search').value.toUpperCase();
  chart.data.datasets[0].backgroundColor = labels.map(v => v.toUpperCase() == searchValue ? 'red' : 'green');
  chart.update();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.4/Chart.min.js"></script>
<input id="search" type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="highlightMatchingBar()" placeholder="Search...">
<canvas id="myChart" height="80"></canvas>
```

Comment: actually any idea how to do it with more than one letter? ie. a full word to search for the labels?

Comment: @hieronymous_vis: I adapted my answer to illustrate how it works with full words.

Comment: is it possible to search more dynamically? ie. if I put 'o', then all of the words with 'o' are highlighted. then, if i continue typing 'og', then it narrows down to 'dog'